# Plotly Dash : Passing data from a callback to another callback with dcc.Store component

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a multi-tab / page application and I'd like to pass the data (a dictionary) returned by a function call in one callback to another callback. Here's some code:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


#app layout

layout = html.Div([

                                   dcc.input(id="comp"),

                                   dcc.Store(id="id1")

                                   html.Div(id='dummy-div')

])

# callbacks

app.callback1([
                            output('comp','value'),
                            output('dummy-div','value'),
                         ],
                         [
                           input('in1','value'),
                           input('in2','value')
                         ],
                        ):
def update(in1, in2):
       # function call

      res = func(in1, in2)

      # for reproducibility
      res = {'name':'xyz', 'addr':'123'}

       return (in2, res)

app.callback(output('id1', 'data'),
                       [
                         input('comp','value'),
                         input('dummy-div','value)
                       ],
                      ):
def store(store, dummy):
   
       # save to store component

      # for reproducibility
      res = {'name':'xyz', 'addr':'123'}
    
     return {'res': res,
                   'comp': 12
                  }
```

I get an dash exception when I run the above code:

```
raise exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue(
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `[<Output `dummy-div.value`>]`
returned a value having type `list`
which is not JSON serializable.


The value in question is either the only value returned,
or is in the top level of the returned list,

and has string representation
`[{'Name':'xyz','Address':'123'........}]`

In general, Dash properties can only be
dash components, strings, dictionaries, numbers, None,
or lists of those.
```

Basically, I'd like to save `res` which is dictionary returned by the function invoked to `dcc.Store` component. I'd need to have two separate callbacks because of the way app is structured. How do I pass `res` to the callback that saves to `dcc.Store` component?